# How to make svn on mac stop ignoring .a files on commit?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, svn

I would like to add .a files on an iOS project to SVN using Xcode, but SVN is apparently ignoring them.

Is there any configuration file where I can set SVN to not ignore these files?
I've tried changing the file in `~/.subversion/config` but this file is completely commented and does not seem to be the one affecting the commit.

I've seen solutions for committing these files through terminal but I would like something a bit more hands free.